# How to convert string to float in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have string and I want to convert into double value. I have written code but sometimes my program is being crashed.

```
double left_operand=[operand_1 doubleValue];
```

Here `operand_1` is NSString variable and i want to convert it into double value. Sometimes above code is crashing my program (automatically closed simulator)

Is above code right?

Comment: Your code is ok. When application crashes check error message in console to see what the problem is

Comment: does look fine, however can you show us the console log after the error and what does the stacktrace look like?

Comment: My error console is showing 

Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Comment: [Enable NSZombie](http://cocoa-nut.de/?p=16) for your active executable and see if the console output yields something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be getting this error because operand_1 is not accessible here because probably you are releasing it above this line or if you are using auto release then you are not retaining it, check for it by `NSLog(@"%@",operand_1);` before the above line if you are getting same error then i m right.

Comment: I am printing it but same error is ocuuring and console is also not showing anything.

Comment: and i also got one thing this is creating problem for 1 of length of string.If i have string length with more than 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
float valueFloat=[*your string* floatValue];
double valueDouble=[*yourstring* doubleValue];
```

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar sometime this also happens when your string contains some special characters check that.